# U-Boot on a Nokia N900

Tags: linux, boot

Ok, I installed u-boot on a Nokia N900 by following these instructions. Installation successful. Next I was trying to install NITDroid. As I was working around, something went wrong, and now my phone does not boot. I am neither able to reflesh it, since when connected by USB to a computer, it is not recognised. I admit I am a newbie to u-boot. I am able to gain access to the boot shell but I do not know how to use it to recovery my phone. Any help?

Comment: There's always the `help` command at the U-Boot prompt.

Comment: Yes, but it scrolls all commands in one time and I cannot read them. It could be a stupid thing, but I haven't found a way to read a screen at a time.

Comment: Then try `mmc info` or `nand info` or `sf probe` to try and figure out what the storage device is.  For more commands try `help mmc` or `help nand`.  `printenv` might be interesting.

Comment: @sawdust mmc info gives me informations which I honestly don't fully understand. I only realize that the memory is partitioned in three parts, and the current one is the first. sf probe doesn't work. printenv is not readable due to screen scrolling. nand info doesn't work.

Comment: Tomorrow I will get a micro SD card and try to create a bootable OS on it with my computer. This should provide a mean to start up the phone.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)